# jqGrid: how to do form edit if all fields do not fit to screen

Tags: jqgrid

jqGrid edit and add forms render every field in separate row. If there are more fields than fit to screen, edit form height is greater than screen. Bottom edit fields are not visible and cannot edited. Form cannot resized since resizer in lower right corner is outside screen.

How to allow editing of all fields ? Is it possible to render more than one field in row, add horizontal scrollbar to edit form or other idea ?

```
        grid.navGrid("#pager", { }, { url: '<%= Url.Action( "Edit", "Grid") %>',
            savekey: [true, 13],
            recreateForm: true, // required for textarea datainit
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            errorTextFormat: function (response) { return response.responseText; },
        }, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Edit/Add option like

```
afterShowForm: function($form) {
    $form.css({overflow: 'scroll'});
}
```

to force the usage of the scroll bar in the form or to change the CSS for `form.FormGrid` with the same `overflow: scroll` value.

You can try to use different values of `height` and `width` property of the Edit/Add option (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties)).

Probably you can solve the problem just by setting of the `cols` and `rows` attributes:

```
edittype:'textarea', editoptions: {rows:"10",cols:"80"}
```

for the corresponding column (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#textarea))

Comment: thank you very much. I was able to solve the issue by using `dataheight: screen.height-200,`

Comment: What if I want to change the `CSS` of the `ADD` `form` other then the css of the `JQGrid` ?